# Why does Emacs sometimes overwrite characters when I insert or delete?

Tags: emacs, insert, overwrite

This happens for me all the time.  Upon insertion/deletion, the positions of other characters in the buffer  are not shifted.

For example, with buffer contents `this is important content`, inserting `very` before `important` results in the two words `very` and `important` appearing overlapped, like this: `this is veryrtant content` instead of `this is very important content`

How can I fix this?

Killing the buffer and reopening of course works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have accidentally turned on `overwrite-mode`.

That command is a toggle.  It is bound by default to the keys `<insertchar>` and `<insert>`.  Typically one of those keys in a keyboard key labeled **Insert**.

But perhaps your keyboard is sending that key when you do something else.

Does the overwriting ever turn off? If so, that would suggest that you accidentally hit the toggle key a second time.

If not, then perhaps your keyboard or terminal is itself somehow locked in an overwriting mode. Do you see the same behavior outside of Emacs?

Comment: i'm using prelude, overwrite-mode undo the effect, don't know the mapping, init files are many, don't know way to find key mapping.

Comment: IME, that is a very common error (IOW, I do that twice a day at least ;-) ) I've just learned to recognize it quickly and hit <Insert>, but maybe I should just disable it. I don't remember the last time I actually *used* overwrite-mode deliberately

Comment: It would be wonderful if there were a simple way to PERMANENTLY retire overwrite mode.